# php variable-less argument?

Tags: php, url

just wondering. i've seen sites with this kind of url http://www.something.com/?somedata with the 'somedata' is the value of some 'unmentioned' variable

how can i do something like that? all I know is the traditional http://www.something.com/index.php?arg=somedata

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

This is just a variable without value. You can get that string using `list($value) = array_keys($_GET);` - assuming you have ensured there is exactly one value in the `$_GET` array (`count($_GET) === 1`), otherwise you will get an error (if `$count === 0`) or unwanted behavior (if `$count > 1`).

Comment: No, it doesn't, *if you know the exact string you're expecting*. I thought of a scenario where you don't know the key, as in `search.php?mysearchstring`. Besides: the question's title is 'variable-less argument'

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. Why does it get downvoted? Any explanation?

Comment: @Pekka: I believe that the question is not clear enough and every understands something different from it. IMHO, the "unmentioned" variable was only an hypothesis of the OP, who was astonished for the lack of `=` sign and didn't even know you can normally omit "index.php" from URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually access the full query string using `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`.

I think every main-stream web server provides that variable, I'm 100% sure about Apache and pretty sure about IIS.

Comment: PHP allows direct access to GET variables via the `$_GET` associative array. There's no need to parse the query string.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, Pekka never metioned parsing anything: this answer is referring to getting the full query string.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a shortcut for a boolean value.

somedata is equivalent to somedata=1 or somedata=true

When it's checked server side, the presence itself of the variable is enough to write a condition.

```
if ( isset($_GET['somedata']) ) { 
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see as "*the value of some 'unmentioned' variable*" is more generally considered as a query string parameter without a value. So for `foo=bar&baz`, `foo` has the value `bar` and `baz` has no value (in PHP its value will be an empty string).

Since the other answers are providing different methods of accessing that parameter name, here are my two cents. You can get the first key of the `$_GET` array by using the [`key`](http://php.net/function.key) function. If no key is available, `key` will return NULL.

**Visiting `?somedata=somevalue`**

```
var_dump(key($_GET), $_GET);
/*
string(8) "somedata"
array(1) {
  ["somedata"]=>
  string(9) "somevalue"
}
*/
```

**Visiting `?somedata`**

```
var_dump(key($_GET), $_GET);
/*
string(8) "somedata"
array(1) {
  ["somedata"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
*/
```

**Visiting `?`**

```
var_dump(key($_GET), $_GET);
/*
NULL
array(0) {
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

They probably use some kind of URL rewriting (see [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) mod_rewrite) where the url is transformed from http://www.something.com/?somedata to http://www.something.com/index.php?arg=somedata

Comment: Not in this case - this is a perfectly normal query string, no rewriting needed.

Comment: URL rewriting for clean URLs would produce something like "http://www.something.com/index/somedata"

Answer (score 0):

For your given URL you can just iterate over the $_GET array:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'somedata') {
        //do something
    }
}
```

You'll find the parameter in the keys of $_GET.

You also could extract the keys from $_GET with `array_keys($_GET)`.

Answer (score 0):

Most web servers, since the beginning of the web, allow to define a default file name to be delivered for directories. So if you load http://example.com/ it serves such file (typically `index.html`). In PHP enabled systems, you normally use `index.php` for such purposes, although the exact name can be changed. In Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

As about `?somedata`, it's just a variable without a value (or, more exactly, its value is an empty string). You can use it if you only need to know whether the variable is set or not:

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['somedata']) ){
    // Do some stuff
}

?>
```